# Android xml complicated layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I can't figure out the Android xml outline for this:
Three linear layouts on top of each other where **1** and **2** have equal heights regardless of content and **3** is wrap content
 
[image]

**3** will have a height of wrap content, and then I want **1** and **2** to have equal heights that take up all the space above of **3** regardless of their contents. The problem I'm running into is that **1** and **2** don't equally divide the space. **3** needs to also be aligned to the bottom.

Things I've tried:

1. everything is in a relative layout, and then putting **1** and **2** in a linear layout where each have weight of 1.  -- this doesn't work because each **1**, **2**, and **3** each consist of a row of 3 buttons that have their respective weights, so I get the error "don't nest weights".
2. in a relative layout, just align **3** to the bottom, and then **1** and **2** are "above" and "below" the others respectively. -- This doesn't evenly space out **1** and **2**

Any other ideas? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks! :D

(I struggled on this long enough that I created my first stackoverflow account!)

EDIT 1: Clarify that **1** and **2** are linear layouts of 3 buttons each, oriented horizontally with weight_sum=3 and each button has weight=1 (hence the issue with nesting weights).

Comment: put your xml layout..

Comment: as you explain in the Question. I don't Understand but you want the Image type of layout Am I Right ?

Comment: what's not clear to me, do you want all 3 layouts to fit the screen? like, the first 2 have fix height and the third fills remaining space, or you want to scroll the whole thing?

Comment: @lelloman I want all three to be in the screen, but not necessarily fixed heights. Just that 1 and 2 are the same height, filling up the space that 3 does not fill up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LinearLayout` as parent layout. Add 3 `LinearLayouts` in it and apply `layout_weight` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inv_main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can test by adding `TextView` or any `Widget` inside 3rd `layout` it will grow as it has `weight 0`. `layout_weight 0` is given when `layout` has to be given space and it will not be ignored by it's parent and `layout_weight 1` for other 2 above `layouts` will give them equal heights.

Comment: @joshua has my answer helped you?

Comment: Nikhil, so far this is pretty much exactly what I want. Is there a way to get rid of the "dont nest weights" warning? (clarified in the question) **1** and **2** are linear layouts of horizontally oriented buttons each with weight 3. Any suggestions for this? Thanks a lot so far!

Answer (score 0):

Your should use weight with `LinearLayout` not with `Relative`,i guess this is what you want, you can add widgets inside them or can replace them with any widgets using same required attributes(weights ,height,width)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#00efff"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="#19bdda"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="#65edda"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weights should be used with Linear layout only and avoid nesting of weights. It takes more time to render views with weights. 
Dont nest layouts also , Use best practices for android. Nesting linear layout inside Relative layout, instead you can use linear layout only with weights.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="2">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```